# Subtraction in Mysql based on column value and group by

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my table structure

[image]

I need to subtract Deposit And Withdrawal based on GROUP BY Bank

Expected Output

```
Bank  balance

1     1000.00

2     300.00

3     500.00
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this in one group by clause.

Comment: Please provide us with the code you already tried to achieve this, we're here to help you solve a problem you're having, not your code minions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use case  when

```
    select  bank,  sum( case when  bankType ='Withdrawal' 
                          then -BankRs 
                          else  BankRs  end ) balance
    from your_table  
    group by bank
```

Comment: @RBT  answer updated  with the more simple case when  solution